# Google YouTube Fetching Video Searchbykeyword Wrong Result.?

Tags: c#, google-api

I am working with WPF application in that case I am using Google API and Retriving Query using YouTubeQuery but I am getting Wrong result it will show me shome unneccesary result which is not contain my searchKey word my Query like this.

```
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("YourApplicationName", "DeveloperKey");
    YouTubeRequest request;
    private const string SEARCH = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={0}&v=2";
        request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
        YouTubeQuery myQuery = new YouTubeQuery(string.Format(SEARCH, args.RequestedPageData.FirstOrDefault()));
        myQuery.OrderBy = "viewCount";
        Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(myQuery);
        foreach (Video item in videoFeed.Entries)
        {
            foreach (var item1 in item.Thumbnails)
            {
                item.Keywords = item1.Url;
                break;
            }
            VideoList.Add(new YouTubeVideoListItem()
            {
                Title = item.Title,
                Description = item.Description,
                Username = item.Uploader,
                Thumbnail = item.Keywords,
                NumberOfViews = item.ViewCount,
                RunningTimeOfVideo = (Convert.ToInt32(item.Media.Duration.Seconds) / 60).ToString(),
                SearchTitle = "Search Result",
                Posted = ((Google.GData.Client.AtomEntry)(item.YouTubeEntry)).Published.ToShortDateString(),
                VideoUrl = item.WatchPage.AbsoluteUri
            });
        }
```

where I am wrong I dont know can anybody update me is there any work around for this.
it greate help me.

Thank you..!!

[image]

Comment: Do you get wrong results for every search, or only some of them?

Comment: Yes I am getting Every Search wrong result.

Comment: Do a search for something and put a breakpoint after `myQuery` has been set. Copy the value of `myQuery` and paste it here so we can see what the query looks like.

Comment: Once I put the Breakpoin and check the value of the myQuery it will give me the BaseAddress like this.->http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=windows phone 7&v=2

Comment: I am addin sreen short so you can more clear about this and my searchkeyword is windows phone 7

Comment: Typing that into a webbrowser, the results look normal. What are the first few videos you're getting when you run it in your app?

Comment: it will give me some another videos this is not related to my searchkeyword.

Comment: What if you remove orderBy viewCount?

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you @keyboardP I make as answer I am phasing this issue almost couple of days but I could't find out. thank you once again for you responce.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped :) I've posted it as an answer and what I think might've happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `viewCount` property. It might be the case that the view count is returning the reverse order, so the first videos displayed are those with the least view counts, which are usually unrelated videos. If you want to keep the viewCount, try iterating backwards over the results.